# Keras model LSTM predict 2 features

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, prediction

I am trying to predict 2 features. This is how my model looks like:

### Defining the model

```
def my_model():
    input_x = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, look_back, x_train.shape[2]), name='input')
    drop = Dropout(0.5)

    lstm_1 = LSTM(100, return_sequences=True, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, x_train.shape[2]), name='3dLSTM', stateful=True)(input_x)
    lstm_1_drop = drop(lstm_1)
    lstm_2 = LSTM(100, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, x_train.shape[2]), name='2dLSTM', stateful=True)(lstm_1_drop)
    lstm_2_drop = drop(lstm_2)

    y1 = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='op1')(lstm_2_drop)
    y2 = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='op2')(lstm_2_drop)

    model = Model(inputs=input_x, outputs=[y1,y2])
    optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001, decay=0.00001)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer,metrics=['mse'])
    model.summary()
    return model

model = my_model()

for j in range(50):
    start = time.time()
    history = model.fit(x_train, [y_11_train,y_22_train], epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0, shuffle=False)
    model.reset_states()
    print("Epoch",j, time.time()-start,"s")

p = model.predict(x_test, batch_size=batch_size)
```

My data set has 9 features:

```
x_train (31251, 6, 9)
y_11_train (31251,)
y_22_train (31251,)
x_test (13399, 6, 9)
y_11_test (13399,)
y_22_test (13399,)
```

I am trying to predict the first(`y_11`) and second(`y_22`) feature of my dataset. But I am getting prediction for only first feature not the second one.

Any help on how can I get both the predictions instead of one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should remove multiple inputs of the same thing:

> (batch_size, look_back, x_train.shape[2])

Also, try to concatenate your ouputs inside your model like this:

```
def my_model():
    from keras.layers import concatenate

    lstm_1 = LSTM(100, return_sequences=True, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, x_train.shape[2]), name='3dLSTM', stateful=True)
    lstm_1_drop = drop(lstm_1)
    lstm_2 = LSTM(100, name='2dLSTM', stateful=True)(lstm_1_drop)
    lstm_2_drop = drop(lstm_2)

    y1 = Dense(1, activation='linear', name='op1')(lstm_2_drop)
    y2 = Dense(1, activation='linear', name='op2')(lstm_2_drop)

    y= concatenate([y1,y2])

    model = Model(inputs=input_x, outputs=y)
    optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001, decay=0.00001)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer,metrics=['mse'])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

EDIT
I think you should fit like this:

```
y_11_train = y_11_train.reshape(y_11_train.shape[0],1)
y_22_train = y_22_train.reshape(y_22_train.shape[0],1)
model = my_model()
model.fit(x_train,np.concatenate((y_11_train,y_22_train),axis=1),...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Didnt quite get this `First of all you should remove multiple inputs of the same thing:` and you haven't defined `input_x` anywhere. I guess you meant the same way I have defined `input_x` as above? Also once we concatenate in `y` I am not sure how the model.fit would look like. Can you share that part as well? Thanks again :) @Ioannis

Comment: If I fit like this `model.fit(x_train,[y_11_train,y_22_train],...)` it gives an error: `ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 arrays but instead got the following list of 2 arrays: [array([ 1. ,  1. ,  0.5, ...,  0. ,  0. ,  1. ]), array([ 0.00486618,  0.01459854,  0.00973236, ...,  0.00243309,
        0.00243309,  0.00243309])]...` because in the model I am putting the concat of `y1` and `y2` as y

Comment: Thanks again @Ioannis. Now after your last edit I am not getting any error, but still the prediction for y_22 is still 0. The output looks like this `[ 0.58788115  0.        ]
[ 0.61794746  0.        ]
[ 0.63426572  0.        ]
[ 0.61786509  0.        ]
[ 0.60721409  0.        ]
[ 0.6071707  0.       ]
[ 0.63450491  0.        ]
[ 0.64836508  0.        ]
[ 0.63034999  0.        ]`

Comment: try linear activations on y1, y2 layers instead of relu (i have modified my answer)

Comment: wow man!!! It worked. Thank you so so muucch!!!! You are a legend! Just curious do you know why the change from relu to linear did the trick? Thanks again :)

Comment: we usually use linear for regression and sigmoid or soft max for classification on output layers.